how to make drive bootable
I have an old Debian system whose hard drive failed. I connected the drive to a working system and pulled all the data off of the root partition using dd. It looks to me like all the data is fine, so I decided to just copy it onto a new drive and make it bootable. So I got a new drive, partitioned it, mounted the first partition, and copied all the data onto that partition. My system is Legacy, not EFI. I edited the /etc/fstab on that partition to change the UUIDs to those of the new drive. I ran grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/newdriveroot/boot /dev/sdb to make it bootable, and I edited the /boot/grub/grub.cfg on that partition to change the UUID of the root partition to the new drive's first partition.
When I try to boot from it, Grub loads, presenting the menu just like it would before the old drive died. When I pick the default choice, Linux begins to boot. It clears the screen and then:
Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...

then clears the screen again and then:
Loading, please wait...
[    4.882479] EXT4-fs (sda1): error loading journal
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/e14dc4cb-4b45-8418-e7a6-b2c8d6036749 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

Then it drops me into the built-in shell with the (initramfs) prompt.
Trying to fix it
At that point I am able to mount the root partition using:
mount -o ro,noload /dev/sda1 /root

though I don't know what good that does me. (If I then exit the shell, the boot process tries to continue, but it just leads to errors about /root/sys and /root/proc not existing.) But perhaps the fact that both the ro and the noload are necessary in order to get it to mount is helpful information? And now is probably a good time to remember that when it's connected to a working system, I can mount the partition without a problem (neither ro nor noload needed).
I don't know what to look for in dmesg output; the only thing that I notice is that just before the above journal error, there is a line that says:
JBD2: Unrecognised features on journal

I have run fsck and fsck -f, but no problems were found.
Similar problems
I have found no posts like the situation I am encountering. Specifically, every "error loading journal" error occurs along with errors found by fsck or an inability to mount the partition. In my situation, fsck finds nothing, and the partition can be mounted without a problem from a working system.
System information
What else would be helpful for me to post? Any Grub files? I don't suppose it matters, but here is the output from lsblk, when connected to my working system:
$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0    20G  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
├─sdb5   8:21   0    10G  0 part
├─sdb6   8:22   0     8G  0 part
├─sdb7   8:23   0     2G  0 part
└─sdb8   8:24   0  79.2G  0 part

(I partitioned sdb6 as a swap partition.  5 is intended for /var, 7 for /tmp, and 8 for /home.)
Here is the /etc/fstab (UUIDs deleted for readability):
UUID=<...>  /      ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
UUID=<...>  /home  ext4  defaults           0  2
UUID=<...>  /tmp   ext4  defaults           0  2
UUID=<...>  /var   ext4  defaults           0  2
UUID=<...>  none   swap  sw                 0  0

Am I missing some big step in making the drive bootable?

The root filesystem needs to have empty directories at what will be /dev, /proc and /sys so that devtmpfs, procfs and sysfs virtual filesystems can be mounted on them - did you forget to create those directories after copying the data? The error message unrecognised features on journal suggests the mkfs.ext4 command you used to create the filesystem supports more features than the old kernel's ext4 filesystem driver - you might need to use tune2fs to turn some of the journal features off to for backwards compatibility.

How is/was the disk partitioned? If the disk failed, dd might have copied faulty data. I would prefer GNU ddrescue over dd for copying data from a failed disk. Instead of trying to boot from the possibly faulty copy of the disk, I suggest to install a fresh system and only copy the documents or user specific data from the copy of your failed disk to the new system.

I use the below instructions to make second drive bootable as the working one:
mount /dev/target1 /mnt
rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /mnt
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/target
update-grub2 /dev/target
exit
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt

You can solve your problem if you adapt these instructions to your need.
target and target1 here are disk and partition of the target drive.
What you need is to install grub on the target drive but it takes the whole above instructions.
